# How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?

Tags: javascript, decode, urldecode

I'm not sure what this is called so I'm having trouble searching for it. How can I decode a string with unicode from `http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fexample.com` to `http://example.com` with JavaScript? I tried `unescape`, `decodeURI`, and `decodeURIComponent` so I guess the only thing left is string replace.

EDIT: The string is not typed, but rather a substring from another piece of code. So to solve the problem you have to start with something like this:

```
var s = 'http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com';
```

I hope that shows why unescape() doesn't work.

Comment: Where does the string come from?

Comment: @Cameron: The string is from a script which I called innerHTML on to get. This is why alex's answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

**Edit (2017-10-12)**:

@MechaLynx and @Kevin-Weber note that [`unescape()` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) from non-browser environments and does not exist in TypeScript. `decodeURIComponent` is a drop-in replacement. For broader compatibility, use the below instead:

```
decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse('"http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com"'));
> 'http://example.com'
```

Original answer:

```
unescape(JSON.parse('"http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com"'));
> 'http://example.com'
```

You can offload all the work to `JSON.parse`

Comment: Interesting. I did had to add quotes around it `unescape(JSON.parse('"' + s + '"'));` What is the reason for the extra quotes? Does that make it valid JSON?

Comment: Note that this appears to be significantly faster than the `fromCharCode` approach: http://jsperf.com/unicode-func-vs-json-parse

Comment: Important note about @styfle's answer: Don't use `JSON.parse('"' + s + '"')` when dealing with untrusted data use `JSON.parse('"' + s.replace('"', '\\"') + '"')` instead, otherwise your code *will break* when the input contains quotes.

Comment: Many manu thank's for this hack. It works perfectly ! Thanks too to @alexander255 which pointed out an important improvement.

Comment: Great answer @alexander255, but you would actually want to use:

JSON.parse('"' + str.replace(/\"/g, '\\"' + '"')

to replace ALL occurrences of that character throughout the string, rather than replace one.

Comment: Yes, definitely use `.replace(/\"/g, '\\"')`! `.replace('"', '\\"')` looked great back then, but unfortunately wasn't actually :-(

Comment: For those who come across this and are worried because `unescape()` has been deprecated, `decodeURIComponent()` works identically to `unescape()` in this case, so just replace it with that and you're good.

Comment: `JSON.parse('"http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com"')` is giving me ` unexpected token at '"http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fexample.com"'`

Comment: @jrochkind - I don't get any errors here on NodeJS 9.x, Chrome or Safari - what environment gives that for you?

Comment: This doesn't work for x escapes like `\x61` or for the new Unicode escapes like `\u{1F4A9}`.

Answer (score 130):

**UPDATE**: Please note that this is a solution that should apply to older browsers or non-browser platforms, and is kept alive for instructional purposes. Please refer to @radicand 's answer below for a more up to date answer.

---

This is a unicode, escaped string. First the string was escaped, then encoded with unicode. To convert back to normal:

```
var x = "http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com";
var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
x = x.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)); } );
console.log(x);  // http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
x = unescape(x);
console.log(x);  // http://example.com
```

To explain: I use a regular expression to look for `\u0025`. However, since I need only a part of this string for my replace operation, I use parentheses to isolate the part I'm going to reuse, `0025`. This isolated part is called a group.

The `gi` part at the end of the expression denotes it should match all instances in the string, not just the first one, and that the matching should be case insensitive. This might look unnecessary given the example, but it adds versatility.

Now, to convert from one string to the next, I need to execute some steps on each group of each match, and I can't do that by simply transforming the string. Helpfully, the String.replace operation can accept a function, which will be executed for each match. The return of that function will replace the match itself in the string.

I use the second parameter this function accepts, which is the group I need to use, and transform it to the equivalent utf-8 sequence, then use the built - in `unescape` function to decode the string to its proper form.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain a little bit about what you're doing? It looks like the regex is looking for a `\u` prefix and than a 4 character hex number (letters or numbers). How does the function in the replace method work?

Comment: You are right, that needed an explanation, so I've updated my post. Enjoy!

Comment: Great solution.  In my case, I am encoding all international (non-ascii) characters being sent from the server as escaped unicode, then using your function in the browser to decode the characters to the correct UTF-8 characters.  I found that I had to update the following regex in order to catch characters from all languages (i.e. Thai):
`var r = /\\u([\d\w]{1,})/gi;`

Comment: Note that this appears to be significantly slower than the `JSON.parse` approach: http://jsperf.com/unicode-func-vs-json-parse

Comment: This answer uses a solution that is deprecated:

"The unescape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5."

Comment: There is no such thing as deprecation in Javascript. Older browsers must always be supported, or at least for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas There most certainly is such a thing as deprecation in Javascript. To claim that and then support it by stating that older browsers must always be supported is a completely ahistorical perspective. In any case, anyone who wants to use this and also wants to avoid `unescape()` can use `decodeURIComponent()` instead. It works identically in this case. I would recommend radicand's approach however, as it is simpler, just as supported and faster to execute, with the same results (make sure to read the comments however).

Comment: @MechaLynx Well, in principle of course you could argue that there is deprecation in Javascript. In practice, it is a different matter altogether. If you have the option to support only new browsers / versions, then you are lucky. As is frequently the case however, ALL browsers need to be supported. From that perspective, you cannot consider even the crappiest, most obscure Javascript "feature" as deprecated, ever. This is why most mature web UI frameworks still (and probably forever will) provide polyfills for old web browsers.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas You're confusing "deprecated" with "obsolete". On top of that, you're using depreciation in a completely absolute sense, which is meaningless. Do you never check what user base a website has and what browser distribution is used among visitors? Depending on the audience and browser distribution, you _can_ ignore certain browsers just fine. Nothing would have ever changed since the 90s if developers didn't give up on old technology - hence why I said this perspective of yours is ahistorical. Deprecation happens - in practice, not just theory or principle.

Comment: @MechaLynx I think you can understand that there are many, many old apps out there, and that in many cases, user base and browser distribution are exactly the problem. We can argue semantics all day, but the unfortunate fact is that this answer, as well as other such "deprecated" answers still get upvotes - to my astonishment - to this day. As for my perspective, it is purposefully ahistorical, as you correctly suggest, when dealing with this language. Perhaps there will come a day when we can phase out hacks such as the above, but that is nowhere in the near future.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas you talk about this answer as if it's not yours and you can do nothing about it. `decodeURIComponent()` exists even as far back as IE6, `JSON.parse()` exists since IE8 and the charts don't even show anything below IE11 anymore: http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-partially-combined-market-share#monthly-201609-201709-bar - to be blunt, there is nothing here that you can't change to using those, unless you're going to argue that clunky code running on 100% of browsers is worth it so that you can support less than 0.86% of browsers, IE6/7 being only part of that.

Comment: @MechaLynx I am not quite sure what's being debated here anymore, but I think we are past the point where it was constructive. The fact is that I will not do anything to change this answer, because I believe it holds instructional value, and is still relevant.

Comment: It helped me. JSON.parse doesn't decode inner JSON, like "value":"\"a\":\"b\""

Answer (score 22):

Note that the use of `unescape()` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) and doesn't work with the TypeScript compiler, for example.

Based on radicand's answer and the comments section below, here's an updated solution:

```
var string = "http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com";
decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse('"' + string.replace(/\"/g, '\\"') + '"'));
```

`http://example.com`

Comment: This doesn't work for some strings, as quotes can break the JSON string and result in JSON parsing errors. I used the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885499/249327) in these cases.

Answer (score 10):

Using `JSON.decode` for this comes with significant drawbacks that you must be aware of:

- You must wrap the string in double quotes
- Many characters are not supported and must be escaped themselves. For example, passing any of the following to `JSON.decode` (after wrapping them in double quotes) will error even though these are all valid: `\\n`, `\n`, `\\0`, `a"a`
- It does not support hexadecimal escapes: `\\x45`
- It does not support Unicode code point sequences: `\\u{045}`

There are other caveats as well. Essentially, using `JSON.decode` for this purpose is a hack and doesn't work the way you might always expect. You should stick with using the `JSON` library to handle JSON, not for string operations.

---

I recently ran into this issue myself and wanted a robust decoder, so I ended up writing one myself. It's complete and thoroughly tested and is available here: https://github.com/iansan5653/unraw. It mimics the JavaScript standard as closely as possible.

#### Explanation:

The source is about 250 lines so I won't include it all here, but essentially it uses the following Regex to find all escape sequences and then parses them using `parseInt(string, 16)` to decode the base-16 numbers and then `String.fromCodePoint(number)` to get the corresponding character:

```
/\\(?:(\\)|x([\s\S]{0,2})|u(\{[^}]*\}?)|u([\s\S]{4})\\u([^{][\s\S]{0,3})|u([\s\S]{0,4})|([0-3]?[0-7]{1,2})|([\s\S])|$)/g
```

Commented (NOTE: This regex matches all escape sequences, including invalid ones. If the string would throw an error in JS, it throws an error in my library [ie, `'\x!!'` will error]):

```text
/
\\ # All escape sequences start with a backslash
(?: # Starts a group of 'or' statements
(\\) # If a second backslash is encountered, stop there (it's an escaped slash)
| # or
x([\s\S]{0,2}) # Match valid hexadecimal sequences
| # or
u(\{[^}]*\}?) # Match valid code point sequences
| # or
u([\s\S]{4})\\u([^{][\s\S]{0,3}) # Match surrogate code points which get parsed together
| # or
u([\s\S]{0,4}) # Match non-surrogate Unicode sequences
| # or
([0-3]?[0-7]{1,2}) # Match deprecated octal sequences
| # or
([\s\S]) # Match anything else ('.' doesn't match newlines)
| # or
$ # Match the end of the string
) # End the group of 'or' statements
/g # Match as many instances as there are
```

#### Example

Using that library:

```js
import unraw from "unraw";

let step1 = unraw('http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com');
// yields "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com"
// Then you can use decodeURIComponent to further decode it:
let step2 = decodeURIComponent(step1);
// yields http://example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough rep to put this under comments to the existing answers:

`unescape` is only deprecated for working with URIs (or any encoded utf-8) which is probably the case for most people's needs. `encodeURIComponent` converts a js string to escaped UTF-8 and `decodeURIComponent` only works on escaped UTF-8 bytes. It throws an error for something like `decodeURIComponent('%a9'); // error` because extended ascii isn't valid utf-8 (even though that's still a unicode value), whereas `unescape('%a9'); // ©` So you need to know your data when using decodeURIComponent.

decodeURIComponent won't work on `"%C2"` or any lone byte over `0x7f` because in utf-8 that indicates part of a surrogate. However `decodeURIComponent("%C2%A9") //gives you ©` Unescape wouldn't work properly on that `// Â©` AND it wouldn't throw an error, so unescape can lead to buggy code if you don't know your data.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to this exact question, but for those who are hitting this page via a search result and who are trying to (like I was) construct a single Unicode character given a sequence of escaped codepoints, note that you can pass multiple arguments to [`String.fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) like so:

```
String.fromCodePoint(parseInt("1F469", 16), parseInt("200D", 16), parseInt("1F4BC", 16)) // ‍
```

You can of course parse your string to extract the hex codepoint strings and then do something like:

```
let codePoints = hexCodePointStrings.map(s => parseInt(s, 16));
let str = String.fromCodePoint(...codePoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to `unescape` HTML file sth like

```js
"\u003Cdiv id=\u0022app\u0022\u003E\r\n    \u003Cdiv data-v-269b6c0d\u003E\r\n        \u003Cdiv data-v-269b6c0d class=\u0022menu\u0022\u003E\r\n    \u003Cdiv data-v-269b6c0d class=\u0022faux_column\u0022\u003E\r\n        \u003Cdiv data-v-269b6c0d class=\u0022row\u0022\u003E\r\n            \u003Cdiv data-v-269b6c0d class=\u0022col-md-12\u0022\u003E\r\n"
```

to

```html
<div id="app">
    <div data-v-269b6c0d>
        <div data-v-269b6c0d class="menu">
    <div data-v-269b6c0d class="faux_column">
        <div data-v-269b6c0d class="row">
            <div data-v-269b6c0d class="col-md-12">
```

Here below works in my case:

```js
const jsEscape = (str: string) => {
  return str.replace(new RegExp("'", 'g'),"\\'");
}

export const decodeUnicodeEntities = (data: any) => {
  return unescape(jsEscape(data));
}

// Use it
const data = ".....";
const unescaped = decodeUnicodeEntities(data); // Unescaped html
```