# Javascript Unicode Escaping Backslash

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp, unicode, unicode-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode)

I'm having a javascript variable, in which i have stored a unicode character.

```
var value = "\\u53d3\\u5f13\\";
```

I'm adding the above value dynamically to a div, due to the extra back slash(\\u) proper unicode value is not shown. But if I Change it to single back slash that is \u instead of \\u . The unicode symbol is correctly shown.

In my environment I can not store the value with single back slash. As the response is from the server side..

Is there anyway to replace the double backslash with single backslash to show the proper unicode?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This one answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not about backslash anymore, it's about what the string literally contains. If you just replaced backslashes, you would just end up with `"u53d3u5f13"`. You can trivially unescape them though (if you don't care that anything \uXXXX will be replaced):

```
function unescapeUnicode( str ) {
    return str.replace( /\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})/g, function(g, m1) {
         return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(m1, 16));
    });
}

var value = "\\u53d3\\u5f13\\";
unescapeUnicode(value);
"叓弓\"
```