# unable to convert unicode character in javascript

Tags: javascript

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FersM/1/)

I have a function as follows in javascript

```
function myfun()
{
  var a = "'\u0c39";
  alert(a);

}
```

When i called this function i am able to see correct letter(This letter is telugu language letter).

My problem is my string is coming from java which is like `"'\\u0c39"`. I used  as follows

```
function myfun()
{
  var a = "'\\u0c39";
  alert(a.replace("\\\\","\\").toString());

}
```

But in alert `'\u0c39` is coming.What might be the mistake here.Please help me.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your code works fine.  Show us an actual problem.

Comment: it is not showing the letter which first time shown

Comment: Does the string literal contain one or two backslashes?

Comment: @FelixKling yes are right i updated that

Comment: You can't get `"\u0c39"` from `"\\u0c39"` by removing backslashes. Hint: there are no backslashes in `"\u0c39"`

Comment: @JanDvorak i did not get u.Can u explain pls

Comment: @PSR `"\u0c39"` is a one-character string. `"\\u0c39"` is its encoded form, a six-character string.

Comment: @JanDvorak so what i need to do now

Comment: @JanDvorak see here i created a link http://jsfiddle.net/FersM/1/

Comment: @SLaks see the link once i created

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7885096 and see if it helps.

Comment: @PSR not sure how to do such unescaping except manually. On hack might be JSON-encode -> do the replacement -> JSON-decode, but I can see problems with that.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, "manually" is a way to go :-)

Comment: @FelixKling this is not working in IE.But working in firefox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working in IE 10 (including back to IE7 mode): http://jsfiddle.net/FersM/2/

Try this:

```
function myfun()
{
  var a = "'\\u0c39";
  a = a.replace(/\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/gi, function (n, hex) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));
  });

  alert(a);

}
```

If you want to understand it, the regular expression is looking for all instances of a backslash (double-escaping needed within a regex literal) followed by exactly 4 hexadecimal digits (of whatever case), and then the function will replace the contents of each sequence thus found with the return value. The return value uses [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to convert a Unicode "code point" value into the actual character, but it requires the code point as a number (decimal), so we must first convert the 4 hex characters (the first parenthetical match, and thus the 2nd argument of the function, with the first argument being the whole sequence match which we don't need) into a decimal using the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function with the base argument as "16".

Comment: it is working for only single character

Comment: if i have var a = "'\\u0c2a\\u0c4d"; it is not working

Comment: I forgot the "g" flag... Added now...

Comment: FYI, the eval() solution is not a safe solution unless you are absolutely sure of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this eval code for that issue

http://jsfiddle.net/6Hmyk/

```
function myfun1()
{
  var a = "'\\u0c39";

   alert(eval('"'+a+'"'));   

}

myfun1();
```

In that code , \\ will change to \ and eval code run this as unicode character

Comment: eval() may work, but it is not a safe solution (unless one happens to know the exact input and know that, for example, the code doesn't add its own quotes to escape out of your string and do something else).