# How to force html to not parse xml string into text input?

Tags: html, asp.net, xml, itemtemplate

I have the following piece of code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="162px" ReadOnly="True" 
        Text='<%# Eval("XMLResponse")%>'   TextMode="MultiLine" Width="447px">
    </asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This returns an xml string from the database and displays it in the input, the problem is that for some reason it parses this xml to ensure that it is valid and it often isn't (I don't have control over the generation of that xml). If the xml is valid the above code works perfectly, if it's not then I get the following error:

> The '=' character, hexadecimal value 0x3D, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 13

I have worked out that, in this particular case (but cases will change), it is because the xml starts like this:

> ?xmlversion='1.0'?

Instead of like this:

> ?xml version="1.0" ?

If I use a HttpUtility.HtmlEncode it loads it into the text box without a problem but then the xml formatting is obviously incorrect. I'm sure there's some simple way of forcing it not to parse the xml but I can't seem to find it online. Your help is most appreciated!

Comment: what about using Html encode

Comment: Hi, thanks Murali but if you reread my last paragraph you will see why it's not the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in case someone else has this same, extremely frustrating, issue. The answer was to use HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode on the database output (XMLResponse in my case) and then to decode the resulting UTF-8 string using a RegEx like the following:

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        var x = $("#TextBox2").val();
        var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
        x = x.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16));
        });
        x = unescape(x);
        $("#TextBox2").val(x);
    });
```

I used the answer found here for help with the RegEx:

[How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode)

Comment: Btw I did first try decoding in JavaScript (one of the hundreds of solutions I tried) after using HtmlEncode on it but this lost some of the formatting and thus did not decode properly.