# Javascript Convert Unicode Embedded strings

Tags: javascript, string

I'm getting passed a string from an API method I have no control over that returns strings with paths that sometimes that look like:
/toplevel/nextlevel/_x0034_33name/myoutput.log

It seems to happens with directory names that start with a number.
In this case the directory name should be '433name'.

I'm guessing that *x0034* represents hex for the character '4', possibly in unicode.

The following Javascript returns '4', which would be correct:

```
String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0034",16))
```

Is there a regex command or conversion utility in Javascript readily available to remove and replace all these characters in the string with their correct equivalents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function unescapeApi(string) {
    return string.replace(/_x([\da-f]{4})_/gi, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16));
    });
}

# example, logs '/433name/myoutput.log'
console.log(unescapeApi('/_x0034_33name/myoutput.log'));
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response!  It tests out OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnostics are okay but a bit off. The 'encoded' part is not just the 'x', it's the entire string `_xhhhh_`.

Try this:

```
x = '/toplevel/nextlevel/_x0034_33name/myoutput.log';
y = x.replace (/_x([0-9A-F]{4})_/gi, function (a,b) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(b,16)); });
```

-- then `y` will hold your parsed path.

(Oh, as F.J. says, this might need the `i` Ignore Case flag as well. Hard to say with such a limited test set of data.)

Answer (score 0):

```
'/toplevel/nextlevel/_x0034_33name/myoutput.log'.replace(/_x[\da-f]{4}_/gi,function(match)  {
return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.substr(2,4),16))
```

});

This will be fine as long as the encodings match