# How to decode a string with unicode and utf-8 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, utf-8

Ok please help - I am having trouble unescaping all the unicode/utf-8 in my javascript string. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode) but I don't understand how to form a regex that covers everything I need. For example, a string I have might be: "\xe2\x80\x98my\u002c union" and I would want an output of 'my, union. I am very very confused about how to deal with this format, I tried looking at [this resource](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_unicode_hex.asp) but I just don't understand how to use or construct a regex. Also, if there is another much easier way to unescape these characters, ideas would be welcome, I am a total beginner at this. I did try `unescape(JSON.parse(mystring))` but this did not work either. Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) with [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape), as detailed in [this blogpost](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.ca/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html)

```
decodeURIComponent(escape('\xe2\x80\x98my\u002c union')) // "‘my, union"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I already tried this option as well after reading that blogpost. I'm not sure why it didn't escape the characters