# Encoding of forward slash ('\u002f') in Java strings

Tags: java, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem with encoding of the forward slash character in Java. I have this program to illustrate what is happening -

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class SlashTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String input = "http:\u002f\u002fgoogle.com";
        System.out.println(input); // Prints "http://google.com"

        String input2 = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("hello.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(input2); //Prints "http:\u002f\u002fgoogle.com"
    }
}
```

The program reads from the file "hello.txt". The content of the file is just -

```
http:\u002f\u002fgoogle.com
```

Note that this is the same as the string 'input'.

Can anyone explain to me why there is a difference in the outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java compiler understands the `\uXXXX` syntax and translates these characters.  If you want to perform this translation, you need to do this yourself.

Note: this doesn't even have to be in a String, you can do things like

\u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006d\u002e\u006f\u0075\u0074\u002e\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0074\u006c\u006e\u0028\u0022\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0022\u0029\u003b

is the same as

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

because the compiler translates these characters before checking the code.

Comment: Thanks. This explains it! I de-compiled the .class file and saw that the string is just `"http://google.com"`.

Comment: @MediumOne a crude way to fix this characters is to do `input2 = input2.replaceAll("\\\\u002f", "/");`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `String` with double backlash to avoid this behaviour, as this:

```
String input = "http:\\u002f\\u002fgoogle.com";
```

It will print you `http:\u002f\u002fgoogle.com`. It is because in a `String` special characters have to been scaped with a backlash `\` before of them.

For more info you can see this: [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who want to convert and escaped unicode url or string to unescaped one
like i did

escaped characters:

```
'http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com';
```

unescaped characters:

```
'http://example.com'
```

use this trick can save you hours ([from radicant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12869914/11374545) ) :

```
decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse('"http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fexample.com"'));
> 'http://example.com'
```