# How do i convert this string to a normal utf-8 string

Tags: javascript, unicode

i have a string like that

```
"\u041b\u0430\u0440\u0430 \u041a\u0440\u043e\u0444\u0442: \u0420\u0430\u0441\u0445\u0438\u0442\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430 \u0433\u0440\u043e\u0431\u043d\u0438\u0446"
```

This is the name of the film **"Tomb Rider"** but it is Russian, i need to convert it to a normal Russian string, which will be looks like **"Лара Крофт"**.

Answer (score 0):

These are Unicode characters, if you wish to decode them in javascript you should remove the leading \u and then utilize `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(unicodeVariable, 16));`

You can replace all instances of '\u' using REGEX or string literal approach, below is the latter.

```
var str = "\u041b\u0430\...\u0446"
str.split("\u").join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just splitting and joining only works if there are no other characters. For your string, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode) can be used as-is.