# Decode string with escaped unicode (5 character)

Tags: javascript, unicode, decode

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode/7885499) works great for escaped unicode with 6 characters (e.g. \u00252F), but it doesn't work for escaped unicode with 5 characters (e.g. \u0000S).  When I put both of these examples in [this unicode converter](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter), they both decode fine.  I'm not sure what the difference is between the 5 and 6 character codes.

Comment: There are no unicode escapings with 5 characters. It's `\u0025`+`2F`, which translates to `%2F`, which you can URI-decode to `/`. That's what the answer you linked does. `\u0000S` is totally nonsensical, a [NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) followed by `S`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now I see my folly and realize that the ajax response a bunch of \u0000 (null) codes embedded for no apparent reason. Now that I know this, I can just strip those out. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, if that AJAX service is returning the data in JSON format, then use a JSON parser, which will automatically handle any escaped characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting Bergis answer here:

There are no unicode escapings with 5 characters. It's \u0025+2F, which translates to %2F, which you can URI-decode to /. That's what the answer you linked does. \u0000S is totally nonsensical, a NULL followed by S