# Why does JS String differ from JSON String?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using [this lib](https://github.com/node-modules/emoji) to display emojis.

I want to get my data from a JSON, but for some reason the lib cannot convert a string from JSON.
When I create my own string with the same data, e.g. '\uD83D\uDE18' it displays without any problem.
`emojis.posts[0].content == '\uD83D\uDE18'` returned false

So my question is, what is the difference between a 'normal' string and a JSON string?

JSON

```
{
   "title": "l\\u2764 you\\uD83D\\uDE18"
}
```

...

```
var emojis = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(emojis.title);
```

returns 'l\u2764 you\uD83D\uDE18'

Creating a JSON in JS

```
var emojis = JSON.parse('{"title": "l\\u2764 you\\uD83D\\uDE18"}');
console.log(emojis.title);
```

returns 'l❤ you'

**Found the answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885499/6216557

> This is a unicode, escaped string. First the string was escaped, then
>   encoded with unicode

Comment: The difference between a normal  string, and a JSON string, is that Douglas Crockpot invented the latter.

Comment: Show some code, how do you parse your input and what format is it in?

Comment: `JSON.parse('"\\uD83D\\uDE18"')` works fine for me, are you certain you properly encoded your JSON source?

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/qk8dkmL9/

Comment: Your JSON is doubly escaped, it has two slashes in front of hex sequences instead of one.

Comment: console.log(unescape(emojis.title)); still returns 'l\u2764 you\uD83D\uDE18'

Comment: Did that answer really help you? escape/unescape are used for URL-encoding, that's a different kind of escaping in no way related to JavaScript (or JSON) string escaping.

Comment: Your second example works because the JSON object is embedded into a JavaScript string literal. JavaScript unwraps the first level of backslashes, and JSON.parse unwraps the second level. That is not the case in your first example.