# decodeURIComponent is both working and not working simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, string, decodeuricomponent

I just can't understand it, but here is my situation.

I have this peace of code:

```
someFunction: function(content){

    content    = content.substr(19005,24);

    console.log('content is: '+content);

    content    = decodeURIComponent(content);

    console.log(typeof content, content);

    var string = '\u0430\u0437\u0443\u0439';

    string     = decodeURIComponent(string);

    console.log(typeof string, string);
}
```

And when I run this on my node.js server it returns this "abnormal" result:

```
content is: \u0430\u0437\u0443\u0439

string \u0430\u0437\u0443\u0439 // but should be "string азуй" as below

string азуй
```

So, how is it actually possible??

1) The same content

2) The same variable type

3) The same (decodeURIComponent) function

- but different results???

P.S. The only difference I see is in origin of `content` and `string` vars. But is this play a role?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode)

Comment: It's not duplicate because I wasn't aware that I have double escape in `content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second string you created is not a string of characters with backslashes inside it. Rather, it's a string of unicode characters. When creating a string in javascript you can escape with the backslash and give a unicode character number. This allows for special characters that are outside the normal type-able keys. (Not completely accurate but you get the idea).

To get this to work you'd need to do this:

```
var string = '\\u0430\\u0437\\u0443\\u0439';
```

This double escape means you actually have backslashes instead of an escape sequence.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#String_literals for more details.

**Edit**: It sounds like you're asking how to go from the first string to the actual unicode characters.  Use this (answer take from [How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode)):

```
var content = content.substr(19005,24);
var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
content = content.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)); } );
content = unescape(content);
```