# C# Convert a Unicode escaped to a string

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, decode

I have a text such as "abc\u001357". It's a parameter in json object which I send from client to server via http.
How can I convert that text to a string like "abc%1357". I tried with Regex to replace characters. But it doesn't work

Thanks for advance

Comment: try unicodeencoding https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode#7885499

Comment: Http has special characters.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.  To encode/decode in c# use : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode() or System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
var str = Uri.EscapeUriString("abc\u001357");
```