# Ajax can't return cyrillic words

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am making ajax call to the database and every word that is saved in cyrillic is returned like: `"[\"\\u043a\\u043d\\u0438\\u0433\\u0430\"]"`. How can i prevent this ? This line of code should be `книга`. This is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/admin/site/searchwords',
    /*contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",*/
    data: {
        query: string
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(data)
        return false;
    }
});
```

I commented `contentType` because it gives me error with it:

> PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index:
>   query'

. Maybe i missunderstood something with them ajax requests. I took a look at another answers but still don't understand how to fix it. The framework is `Yii2`(if that matters somehow).Thank you in advance!

Comment: What if you encode/decode the URI component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode)

Comment: It's already unicode encoded and escaped @Script47. He just need the counter part

Comment: I found where my mistake was. I wanted to foreach it like an array so i changed `stringify` to `parse`. Now it works as i expected.