# jQuery parsing unicode characthers in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, unicode, unicode-escapes

I have a string which basically looks like this:

```
20 pcs 1/4&#034; d 13/32&#034; l shank copper round head solid rivets fasteners
```

or :

```
20 Pcs 1/4&quot; D 13/32&quot; L Shank Copper Round Head Solid Rivets Fasteners
```

Where " should be represented as: " characther...

In my JS method I set the label value to following:

```
function WriteTitle(sentTitle){
 $("#myTitle").text(sentTitle);
}
```

I have tried using methods like decodeURIComponent, unescape or similar to parse these characthers but no luck so far...

How can I parse these into normal characters?

Comment: This may be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode

Answer (score 1):

These are not unicode characters but [HTML entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). You should use `.html()` method, it won't escape them (that's exactly what `.text()` does).

```js
function WriteTitle(sentTitle){
  $("#myTitle").html(sentTitle);
}
```

Comment: @User987 You're welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer.