# Javascript convert Var to UTF8 string

Tags: javascript, string, utf-8, ecmascript-6

I've hit a strange situation that I just can't seem to figure my way out of.
I have a string that contains UTF8 characters (escaped).  I've tried the decodeURIComponent(escape(str)) along with a bunch of other suggested fixes, as yet without success.

I've written this function to take the string, find the escaped characters, and replace them with straight UTF8.

```
var unescapeUTF8 = function(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/\\u.{4}/g);
    if (matches == null) return str;
    for (var item of matches)
    {
        // testing
        console.log(new String(item));
    }
    ....
    ....
    ....
};
```

From testing, I know that if I go `new String("\u0123")` I will get back a string object `String {0: "ģ", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "ģ"}`

It seems no matter what I do to the string in the function above, I can not get it to convert from it's escaped `\u0123` to `ģ`

I've managed to 'create' the issue in my browser by opening developer tools and running the following

```
var x = "\\u0123";
console.log(x); // == "\u0123"
new String(x); // == String {0: "\", 1: "u", 2: "1", 3: "3", 4: "2", 5: "4", length: 6, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "\u1324"}
```

Can anyone figure out how to convert "x" into a UTF8 character please...

Comment: and ``new String((new String("\\u0123")).toString())`` does not work, it seems to be holding onto that prefixing \ somewhere somehow.

Comment: [How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode) ?

Comment: `new String("\u0123")` is a false trail because the string is already that character `new String("\u0123") == "\u0123"` is `true`.

Comment: `\u....` is not a "UTF-8 encoded character", it's a Unicode escape sequence. You cannot tell whether a string is encoded in UTF-8 or something else just by looking at it; you can however tell that the characters in the string represent some escape format.

Comment: re-read the question ``new String("\\u0123") == ģ`` is ``false``  BUT ``new String("\u0123") == 'ģ'`` is ``true``.  BUT again...  ``var x = "\\u0123"; new String(x) == '\u0123'`` is ``false``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since those escape sequences are, at first blush, valid JSON escape sequences, the easiest method is to parse the string as a JSON string:

```js
var x = "\\u0123";
console.log(JSON.parse('"' + x + '"'));
```

Comment: Emphasizing: This answer has nothing to do with UTF-8, which makes sense because it seems that the question has nothing to do with UTF-8 (as observed in a comment on the question). The escapes formatted as "\uABCD" are for UTF-16 code units, which is what JavaScript and JSON do use in strings.