# How to parse unicode string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Here I have a Unicode String like below:

```
const uString = '\u0091\u00e5\u00b8\u0081\u00ef';
```

I want to parse it use Javascript, but no matter what method I use, the result always is:

```
const result = `å¸ï`;
```

I know it's not the true meaning of the Unicode string represent.
So I want to know, it's there some ways to parse it correctly?

Comment: The output is correct, what are you expecting it to be?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode#answer-7885499

Comment: It isn't clear if that's just code you run, or a source file that you are parsing yourself (not just running it directly).