# How to get value of escape sequences inside HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, string, unicode-escapes

I have a textarea, and inside of it, I would like to be able to input text alongside escape sequences.

For example, lets say that inside the textarea is:

`Hello\nWorld`.

Now, If I wanted to print that value to the console by using:

`console.log( document.getElementById('myTextArea').value )`

The output that I would like would be:

```
Hello
World
```

But instead, it outputs:

`Hello\nWorld`

This makes since, because that's what I put in. But I would like to convert these sequences to their actual values

Now I'm sure this is possible with a simple string replace, like:

`str.replaceAll('\\n', '\n')`

But I would like to be able to do this with ANY escape sequence. like:
`\u0000`, `\r`, `\u0020`

So is it possible to extract these sequences from a textarea?

Comment: They're not actually in the value of the `<textarea>`. That escape sequence syntax is JavaScript syntax, and the browser doesn't understand them at all. Such escape sequences are recognized by the JS parser when it's reading your source code and interpreting a string constant in the code.

Comment: Are you saying that you literally type a backslash followed by `n` in the text area? And if so, what if you really hit Enter to include a newline, and then a line of text below the first, how will that influence the intended output?

Comment: Sorry, clarification: the *raw* escape strings are in the value, as you've noticed; what's not in there are the characters which JavaScript would understand if they were in a JavaScript string constant. Probably `eval()` is your best bet, but it will be necessary to protect the page code and avoid syntax errors by sanitizing the value. Also, even if you do that, *invalid* escapes will cause syntax errors.

Comment: @Pointy this works great, except for those "invalid escapes". Is there a way to convert those invalid escapes, then do eval?

Comment: The bottom line here is that you're faced with parsing those sequences according to rules you'll have to define for your own purposes. I don't know anything about your user interface, but dealing with HTML escapes instead of JavaScript escapes might be easier (and safer), because you can let the HTML parser deal with them, and it won't throw exceptions (though of course the string will be garbled).

Comment: The HTML parser can deal with those with this simple trick: create a `<div>` element, set its `.innerHTML`, then read back the `.textContent`. But that won't work with JavaScript escapes unfortunately.

Comment: Try `let output = decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse('"' + str + '"'));`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode

Comment: something like ... [`/\\\\(?=[trn]|u\d{4})/g`](https://regex101.com/r/VuIMp6/1)?

Answer (score 0):

Like @James already mentioned in his comment, the answer to this question can be found here: [How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode)

So, the following snippet should not be seen as an answer, but rather as a demo of how to apply the method described there on two `textarea` fields.

```js
const [src,trg]=[...document.querySelectorAll("textarea")];
function parseText(){
 trg.value=(s=>{
  try{return decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse(`"${s}"`));}
  catch{return s;}
 })(src.value);
}
src.addEventListener("input",parseText);
parseText();
```

```html
<textarea>Oh,%20hello\nworld \u2728\t\u263a</textarea><br>
<textarea></textarea>
```